# How to push local gitlab branch to origin without merging

Tags: git, gitlab

Total gitlab beginner. I have a local gitlab branch called `tmp_b` and a coworker asked for a link to the branch. Basically, I want my local branch visible in gitlab to others for inspection, but not merge. I'm assuming I need to push it to origin but not start a merge. How do I do that?

I use `git push origin my_branch` to push my branch and merge but I don't want to merge just push my local branch. Thank you for your help

Comment: Pushing a new local branch should not start a merge. Maybe another branch with the same name exists already? What is the console output you get?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Pushing doesn't technically merge anything. What is going wrong when you try to do it? What specific issue are you facing?

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple. Push local branch to origin and ignore the "merge request". Just did that and it worked.